# Two PictureBox Showing same picture from database C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have two pictureboxes in form both showing same picture from database

```
               `byte[] Img = (byte[])dr["picture"];
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Img);
                Picture.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                Picture.Refresh();`

                `byte[] Imgm = (byte[])dr["picturem"];
                MemoryStream msm = new MemoryStream(Imgm);
                PictureMadani.Image = Image.FromStream(msm);
                PictureMadani.Refresh();`
```

please someone can help to fix this. I want to load picture and pitcurem in two different pictureboxes.

Thank you.

Comment: Get the data once, create one `Stream`, create the `Image` once and assign it to a variable.  Then, assign that variable to the `Image` properties of both controls.

Comment: kindly can you give an example?

Comment: If you can't follow those simple instructions, there's bigger issues to consider.

Comment: There isn't anything obviously wrong with the code snippet.  So you'll surely have to assume that the issue is with the dbase, it has the same image in both columns.  Review whatever code added the record to the dbase table.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant this is what i detected and i have solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code to do your job

pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("D://myImage.jpg");

pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("D://myImage.jpg");

also you do not need to use stream

Comment: i'm trying to load from sql database